# Circle Ci, serverless-framework, serverless-python-requirements

Tags: aws-cli, serverless-framework, circleci, cicd

I am trying to upload my Python project to an AWS account via `circleci CI/CD` but when I deploy the code it always stops and remove docker "docker run --rm -v" in logs

I'm using *ORBs* like

`aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3`

`serverless-framework: circleci/serverless-framework@2.0.0`

any help?

this is .circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3
  serverless-framework: circleci/serverless-framework@2.0.0
jobs:
  deploy:
    executor: serverless-framework/default
    docker: # run the steps with Docker
      - image: cimg/python:3.8.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-cli/setup
      - serverless-framework/setup
      - run:
          name: Install plugins
          command: |
            serverless plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
      - run: python --version
      - run:
          name: deploy
          command: |
            sls deploy --stage dev --verbose
            sls doctor
workflows:
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy
```

And serverless.yml file is

```
service: myapp-api

frameworkVersion: "3"

package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!.vscode'
    - '!.circleci'
    - '!temp.txt'
    - '!README.md'
    - '!env/**'
    - '!package.json'
    - '!package-lock.json'
    - '!others/*.yml'
    - '!resources'

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  endpointType: REGIONAL
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-east-2

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    slim: true
    zip: true

functions:
  # others & publics
  - ${file(./others/TestGet.yml)}
  - ${file(./others/DownloadFactsPost.yml)}
  - ${file(./others/DownloadTagsPost.yml)}

resources:
  # api gateway
  - ${file(./resources/api-gateway-request-validator.yml)}
```

this is the provided error log

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying myapp-api to stage dev (*********)

Adding Python requirements helper
Generated requirements from /home/circleci/project/requirements.txt in /home/circleci/project/.serverless/requirements.txt
Installing requirements from "/home/circleci/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/6b1b8e5bcb3893228e019bffa40e9c7db43bac76b8b7f2766f061ca751e722ce_x86_64_slspyc/requirements.txt"
Docker Image: public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8:latest-x86_64
Using download cache directory /home/circleci/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc
Running docker run --rm -v /home/circleci/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/6b1b8e5bcb3893228e019bffa40e9c7db43bac76b8b7f2766f061ca751e722ce_x86_64_slspyc\:/var/task\:z -v /home/circleci/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc\:/var/useDownloadCache\:z public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8\:latest-x86_64 /bin/sh -c 'chown -R 0\\:0 /var/useDownloadCache && python3.8 -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt --cache-dir /var/useDownloadCache && chown -R 3434\\:3434 /var/task && chown -R 3434\\:3434 /var/useDownloadCache && find /var/task -name \\*.so -exec strip \\{\\} \\;'...

× Stack myapp-api-dev failed to deploy (0s)
Environment: linux, node 16.16.0, framework 3.25.1 (local) 3.25.1v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, environment variables
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Running "docker run --rm -v /home/circleci/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/6b1b8e5bcb3893228e019bffa40e9c7db43bac76b8b7f2766f061ca751e722ce_x86_64_slspyc:/var/task:z -v /home/circleci/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc:/var/useDownloadCache:z public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8:latest-x86_64 /bin/sh -c chown -R 0\:0 /var/useDownloadCache && python3.8 -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt --cache-dir /var/useDownloadCache && chown -R 3434\:3434 /var/task && chown -R 3434\:3434 /var/useDownloadCache && find /var/task -name \*.so -exec strip \{\} \;" failed with: "docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'."

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Docker doesn't running while you are using orbs `aws-cli` and `serverless-framework`

So the solution will be to build it by your own.

this is .circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1

jobs:

  deploy:

    docker: # run the steps with Docker
      # Specify the version you desire here https://circleci.com/developer/images
      - image: cimg/python:3.8-node

    steps: # a set of executable commands
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv env
            . env/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
          paths:
            - env

      - run:
          name: Update NPM
          command: |
            npm install -g npm

      - run:
          name: Install serverless framework
          command: |
            npm install -g serverless

      - run:
          name: Install serverless plugins
          command: |
            sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements

      - run:
          name: deploy
          command: |
            sls deploy --stage dev --verbose
            sls doctor
workflows:
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy
```

And serverless.yml file is

```
service: myapp-api

frameworkVersion: "3"

package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!.vscode'
    - '!.circleci'
    - '!temp.txt'
    - '!README.md'
    - '!env/**'
    - '!package.json'
    - '!package-lock.json'
    - '!others/*.yml'
    - '!resources'

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  endpointType: REGIONAL
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-east-2

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
#   - serverless-reqvalidator-plugin
#   - serverless-aws-documentation

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    noDeploy:
      - boto3
      - botocore
      - docutils
      - autopep8
      - pycodestyle
      - six
      - tomli

functions:
  # others & publics
  - ${file(./others/TestGet.yml)}
  - ${file(./others/DownloadFactsPost.yml)}
  - ${file(./others/DownloadTagsPost.yml)}

resources:
  # api gateway
  - ${file(./resources/api-gateway-request-validator.yml)}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem of being able to run Docker in your CircleCI job, you need to add `setup_remote_docker` to your `config.yml` file.

https://circleci.com/docs/building-docker-images/

The next problem you might hit could be that it can't find the docker image (since it has the architecture of x86_64 which may not be what your CircleCI job is using). To avoid this, add this to the `serverless-pipeline-plugin` options (which removes the architecture from the image name):

```
    dockerImage: public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.11:latest
```